# Throwing one object which throws an other object

Tags: java

```
public class Exceptions {

    static class Second extends RuntimeException {

        public Second() {
            throw this;
        }
    }

    static class First extends RuntimeException {

        public First() {
            throw new Second();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        throw new First();
    }
}

Result:
Exception in thread "main" Exceptions$Second
    at Exceptions$First.<init>(Exceptions.java:14)
    at Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

Good evening for everyone!
I can't understand result.
Why the exception is thrown by the constructor of class `Second`? Can anyone describe the sequence of the steps?

Comment: You never instantiated `First`, since it threw an exception (`Second`) during construction.  You have to create an object before you can throw it.

Comment: @azurefrog That exception never gets thrown.

Comment: Secondary question: If I change `throw this;` to `throw new RuntimeException("something");`, then line 6 (or 7) appears in the backtrace.  But as written, with `throw this;`, the first line of the backtrace is line 13 (or 14).  So what happened to `throw this;`?  Did that `throw` never really happen?

Comment: On looking into my own question further: it looks like `throw this;` actually does cause an exception to be thrown, but the line number of `throw this;` is omitted from the backtrace for some unknown reason.

Comment: I got an answer to this question.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252034/throw-this-results-in-strange-line-in-backtrace .

Answer (score 4):

Before a `throw` statement actually does any throwing, its argument must be evaluated.

```
throw new First();
```

This takes us to the `First` constructor:

```
public First() {
    throw new Second();
}
```

which takes us to the `Second` constructor (again *before* the `throw` can be executed). The `Second` constructor throws an uncaught exception (itself in this case) which is what you see.

Comment: What does the call to `super()` have to do with anything?

Comment: @Alex I misread the OP's code snippet. See the edit -- `super` doesn't come into play as you indicate.

Answer (score 1):

You see the exception because constructor initialization happens before the `throw`.

The cause is simple. When you do a `new First()` you create an object of type First, in the constructor of `First` you call `Second` and that throws a `this`, which is `Second`.

The source of the error is because you are throwing a new Second().

Your class can be like this and you'll continue seeing the error:

```
public class Exceptions {

    static class Second extends RuntimeException {

        public Second() {
            throw this;
        }
    }

    static class First {

        public First() {
            throw new Second();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

throw new First()  constructor creates the second object and before the object is constructed the exception is thrown from second object. You can see this using line at Exceptions$First.(Exceptions.java:14). Hence the object second is never initialised properly for first to do its work and raise exception for main.