# "throw this" results in strange line in backtrace

Tags: java

OK, this is one of the worst examples of programming ever, but I tried it while looking into someone else's question and found the results to be a bit bizarre.  Any explanation?

```
public class Test {

    static class Bizarre extends RuntimeException {

        public void throwMe() {
            throw this;                   // line 6
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bizarre biz = new Bizarre();             // line 12
        System.out.println("Output line 1");     // line 13
        biz.throwMe();                           // line 14
        System.out.println("Output line 2");     // line 15
    }
}
```

Resulting output:

```
Output line 1
Exception in thread "main" Test$Bizarre
        at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

Why line 12?

Comment: You're throwing an exception and not handling it. What did you expect? Note: the exception was created at line 12.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  Line 6, or line 14.  More likely line 6.

Comment: The exception is created at line 12, so that's where the stacktrace will begin.

Comment: If, for some reason, you have a reason to create an exception object and throw it later, you can "update" the stack trace by calling the `fillInStackTrace()` method before you throw it. (That method is called when then exception is constructed to populate the stack trace, which is why it has the stack trace of the place it was created, not thrown.) (You can also override `fillInStackTrace()` to do nothing, if you want to have exceptions that don't carry around stack traces. They're faster to create, but not as useful.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `Exception`'s (`Throwable` really) stack trace is created at initialization. Your exception, a `Bizarre` instance, is created at line 12.

Comment: Ah ... I didn't know that (about the timing of where the backtrace was created).  Thanks.

Comment: @ajb That's because, typically, you'll create the `throw`n instance at the location you throw it.